# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field values

Tags: java, reference, static, field

I am new to programming and am just trying to work a bit with arrays. I am in the process of making the methods I want to use on the array, but when I try to pass the actual array through these methods I get the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ArrayPractice extends Arrays
{
    double[] values = new double[11];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //when methods are created run them each once for the array we created and     then print out the result.
        fillArray(values);
        firstLastSwap(values);
        System.out.println(values);

    }


    public void fillArray(double[] array)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = Math.random();
        }
    }

    public void firstLastSwap(double[] array)
    {
        double tempOne = array[0];
        double tempTwo = array[array.length-1];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == array[0])
            {
                array[i] = tempTwo;
            }
            else if(i == array[array.length-1])
            {
                array[i] = tempOne;
            }
        }
    }

    public void shiftElementsLeft(double[] array)
    {

    }

    public void evenElementsToZero(double[] array)
    {

    }

    public void replaceWithBigNeighbor(double[] array)
    {

    }



}
```

Comment: search old questions before posting..

Comment: I did. I don't understand the answers.

Comment: Then you won't understand these.

Answer (score 0):

Put the keyword "static" in front of your global variable:

static double[] values = new double[11];

Main() is a static method and it can only use static fields or variables defined within it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**. Make your methods static that you are accessing in `main()` method.

**option 2:** Create an instance of the class in the main() method and access non-static methods using the instance

```
ArrayPractice AP = new ArrayPractice();
AP. fillArray(values);
```